# Alternative proof showing the intersection of convex sets is also convex

Tags: analysis

I know there are easier ways to show that the intersection of convex sets is also a convex set (i.e. by showing that if $x,y$ are in the intersection then they are also in each of the sets, and since each of the sets are convex then the intersection containing $x,y$ in also convex), but I wanted to come up with a different *proof* utilizing the fact that an open ball containing the points $x,y$ is also convex. Could someone have a look at my alternate *proof* (below) and let me know if it makes sense? Thanks.

Let $C$ be a collection of convex sets $C_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha \in \Gamma$. Consider the special case when $\cap_{\alpha \in \Gamma}C_{\alpha} = \{x_0\}$. Since an open ball centered at $x_0$ (call it $B_{\epsilon}(x_0), \forall \epsilon > 0$) is convex then if $\cap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} C_{\alpha} = \{x_0\}$ then $\cap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} C_{\alpha}$ is also convex. But this is not sufficient, so suppose $x_0,x, y \in \cap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} C_{\alpha}$, then if $x,y$ are also contained within $B_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ then this will be suffient to show $\cap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} C_{\alpha}$ to be convex. Let $S = \{tx + (1-t)y : 0 \leq t \leq 1, t \in \mathbb{R}, x,y \in \cap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} C_{\alpha}\}$ be all the points on a line connecting $x$ to $y$. Define $|S-x_0|$ to be the distance from $x_0$ to any point on the line defined by $S$. Now, choose $\epsilon$ such that

$$|S-x_0| = |tx + (1-t)y - x_0|$$

$$= |t(x-x_0) + (1-t)(y-x_0)|$$

$$\leq t|x-x_0| + (1-t)|y-x_0|$$

$$< t\epsilon + (1-t)\epsilon = \epsilon$$

Then $x,y \in B_{\epsilon}(x_0)$, all of $S \in B_{\epsilon}(x_0)$, and thus the condition for $\cap_{\alpha \in \Gamma}C_{\alpha}$ to be convex is satisfied.

Comment: You only showed that a ball is convex. Convexity is a global property. You can't proving it using local concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes sense because you nowhere stated how you get from "in an open ball" to "convex". Every point in euclidean space, not just the ones you are talking about, is in some open ball, but that obvious does not at all imply that everything that contains a point is convex.

Furthermore, there are logical errors in the rest of your argument. If you claim something for every $ε > 0$, then you **cannot** choose it like you did otherwise you're not proving your claim at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your feedback. I will revisit my entire approach. Again, thanks.

Comment: @MarkWatson: You're very welcome! Take your time to think through it. For this theorem there is essentially no other proof, and it is definitely good to convince oneself of this.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let's forget about the evident logical mistakes of your argument ...I don't know what is your idea, but remember that a square is convex... don't be fooled by your own intuition.

Comment: Haha. Thanks. I appreciate you taking the time to read and respond. I will revisit my approach. This is my first class of this nature. I am totally new to constructing proofs.